# HTML anchor tag download, filename attribute

Tags: php, html

I have a reporting database where the possible attachments are embedded directly on the page as Base64 strings. The `<a>` tag uses a download attribute that supplies the filename.

It is kind of annoying to have to download an attachment type that the browser can natively render (such as an image, audio file, text file, etc.).

Is it possible to use something like `<a filename=$ATTFILENAME data=...>` so that if the user right clicks the link to download it, the filename is already populated?

*(When using `<a download=$ATTFILENAME data=...>` and clicking the link, the filename matches the (PHP) variable `$ATTFILENAME`. Without the download attribute, the file name is "download").*

Comment: "It is kind of annoying to have to download an attachment type that the browser can natively render" - what do you mean by this? What are you trying to do exactly? "Is it possible to use something like `<a filename=$ATTFILENAME data=...>` so that if the user right clicks the link to download it, the filename is already populated?" - that is precisely what the `download` attribute is for (which you appear to already be using)?

Comment: For example, a browser can render a TXT attachment, picture, audio, maybe even a spreadsheet in the browser without having to open the native program to view the file.

Comment: This is a programming question you should be asking on Stackoverflow, not here, and, yes, I do this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is simple.

If you use inline php for templating then a simple `<a download="<?php echo $ATTFILENAME ?>" href="Base64EncodedData">` should solve it.

If you're using a templating system (Smarty, twig, Blade, ...)  then refer to it's documentation on how you can output a string.

These, of course assume that you have a `$ATTFILENAME` variable present in which you have the original file name. If you haven't stored it at upload, then (to my knowledge) there's no way to recover the original file name.

Comment: Is filename an actual attribute?

Comment: Actually... no My bad :) But it does support the download attribute, which does this. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: not working   .  i am using :: <a href="XXXXXXX" target="_blank" download  class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-icon waves-effect waves-themed" style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px"> <i class="fal fa-download"></i> </a>

Comment: The `download` attribute should have a value, the file's name to be exact, and the href attribute should contain the base64 encoded file.
By the way, this solution isn't suited for large files.